# Can we port Asterisk in rtxRTOS

Tags: asterisk, rtx

Currently I'm porting asterisk general purpose OS, but these are heavier OS, so is there any way that we can port asterisk in Real Time OS(RTOS) e.g. rtxRTOS

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, but likly you have rewrite like 10%.

You can use linux-preemtive kernel and start asterisk with realtime priority(see asterisk.conf.sample)

Yes,i know, it is not really realtime, but close.

Comment: Hi arheops, Thanks for reply, we want to know as asterisk is more complex than pjsip so can we compile pjsip with FreeRTOS?